# How to send a message to my phone that my Arduino system is on when turning on my Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors, c++, gsm

i have installed a GSM shield on the Arduino to create security alarm system using PIR SENSOR when ever there motion I will receive a call to my phone.
but i want to add also a line of code which can make my system send me a txt message stating that my system is turned on so i can make sure that when ever i turn my system on i can doule check by getting a message that says that system is turned on successfully
i dont know how to start doing that.
this is the code i did:

```
int PIR = 6;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(96000);
 pinMode (PIR , INPUT );
}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
if (digitalRead (PIR == HIGH)){
  Serial.println("thief detected");
  delay (200);
  Serial.println ("ATD+0197263315;");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("ATH");
  delay(1000);
  
  }
  else digitalWrite (PIR, LOW );
    
}
```

Comment: `if (digitalRead (PIR == HIGH))` is not doing what you think it does.  Look at where your parenthesis are.

Comment: can explain more

Comment: `PIR == HIGH` is false, because `PIR` is `6` and `HIGH` is `1`.  You have `digitalRead(false)`.  `digitalRead` takes type `int`.  Converted to `int`, `false` is `0`.  You have effectively `digitalRead(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can send an SMS using the Arduino [GSM library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSM). Here is a bare bones sketch that sends one pre-set SMS when it starts up, based on [this tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LibraryExamples/GSMExamplesSendSMS):

```
#include <GSM.h>

#define PINNUMBER "1234"
#define REMOTENUMBER "07123456789"
#define TXTMESSAGE "System started!"

GSM gsmAccess;
GSM_SMS sms;

void setup() {
  boolean notConnected = true;

  while (notConnected) {
    if (gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY) {
      notConnected = false;
    } else {
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  sms.beginSMS(REMOTENUM);
  sms.print(TXTMESSAGE);
  sms.endSMS();
}

void loop() {
}
```

If you can't or don't want to use the GSM library, it should also be possible to send an SMS by using the [SoftwareSerial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) library to control your GSM shield using [AT codes](https://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp). Here's [a tutorial](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/SurtrTech/send-sms-text-from-arduino-using-sim800l-gsm-gprs-module-228975) on this approach, which is lighter weight but might be more fiddly to get working, especially if you need a PIN for your SIM card.